# I was banned for drunk driving 4 years ago in the UK. Will this affect my Russian visa application?

Tags: visas, russia, uk-citizens, deception

I am applying for a Russian visa for a visit this summer. Will a completed drunk driving ban (by the UK) affect my visa application? Should I bother to mention it. (It was back in 2012.)

Comment: It's not usually a problem unless you fail to declare it and then they may  have you for deception. They may not let you rent a car or drive.

Comment: I was thinking who the hell is this 4 years old person who was caught driving while drunk... I need to sleep..

Comment: It's worth noting that Russia considers DUI to be an administrative offence rather than a criminal one.

Answer (score 3):

It is highly unlikely that a conviction for drunk driving would influence your visa application, provided you are upfront about it. They are far more likely to be concerned about ensuring you are only going there to visit and will leave within the expiry of the visa and how you will finance yourself while there.

(Source: I have lived in Russia, visited the country many times and have good friends working in the Russian consular services)

Comment: Yes. I answered as someone who has traveled quite a few times to Russia and who has friends working in Russian consular services.

Comment: Excellent. You may want to add the source of your information to the answer, as it adds to the authority of it.

Answer (score 3):

Does the visa application form ask you about driving bans? Obviously, you should be truthful on the application, but there's no reason to volunteer information if you're not asked for it.

For example, looking at http://www.rusembassy.ca/sites/default/files/AppFormVisa_USA.pdf (the forms are slightly different when applying from different countries I believe), it only asks "**Have you ever been arrested or convicted for any offence?**". I believe it's implied that "offence" means criminal offence (so obviously things like parking tickets don't count). The Russian-language version of this form specifically uses the word "**преступления**" which, as I understand it, means specifically criminal offences (though I am not a lawyer and may not be familiar with the nuances of the word definitions). Basically, if your offence wasn't classified as a criminal one, but purely an administrative one, and if you were never arrested, I would probably strongly consider just answering "no" to this question.

Comment: Most driving offences (with the exception of parking tickets etc - which aren't actually *driving* offences so much as misplacement of property ones) are criminal offences in the UK. Drink driving would definitley be so - and the ban handed out by the courts.

Comment: I agree with the first and disagree with the second paragraph of your answer. If in doubt I would rather tell too much than risk refusal/even more trouble for deception.

Comment: @CMaster - Hmm, didn't know that, it's different elsewhere (e.g. in the US, or at least in many US states, as I understand it driving offences are not classified as criminal unless they are especially serious).

Comment: @mts - For some countries I would agree, however given (1) the bureaucratic nature of many Russian government processes that often completely ignore individual circumstances, (2) the near impossibility of this fact being uncovered later, and (3) my high degree of certainty that they're only asking about criminal offences, I would stand by my suggested course of action for something that's not classified as a crime. Of course, if the offence is actually classified as a crime (as CMaster suggests above), then yes, it should be reported on the form.

Comment: @EugeneO The US may not consider those things criminal, but many other places do! eg [US citizens with DUIs have big issues going to Canada, but not the other way around](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/22238/26)

Comment: I realise that speeding might not be a crime in most US states, but surely DUI is?

Comment: @CMaster - perhaps you're right, fortunately I've never had to deal with a DUI charge : ) The only point of my answer was to examine carefully if the charge is classified is criminal, and if it's not - consider not reporting it.

Comment: In many states a non-injury, first-time DUI/DWI *is* a misdemeanor (but still criminal charge) but causing injury or multiple occurrence may up it to a felony.

Comment: Minor moving violations in California are *infractions*, which is below misdemeanors. DUI, however, would be either a misdemeanor or a felony, and is most certainly a crime. I was even called for Jury Duty on a DUI case, although the prosecuting attorney chose to remove me from the jury pool.

Comment: The English legal system abolished the difference between felonies and misdemeanours in the 1960s. Driving under the influence of alcohol is simply an offence: http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/52/section/4?view=plain